# python3 -m pip install ipykernel returns an error permission denied

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ubuntu-18.04

`bash: /usr/lib/command-not-found: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: Permission denied`

this error occured and I am  very new to linux so I don't understand the meaning of it.

and system said that my python3-pip version is already newest.

what can i do for solving this error?

my ubuntu version is 18.04

Comment: also i did it in root! but permission error was  occured..

Answer (score 0):

Enter

sudo python3 -m pip install ipykernel

Enter password

Comment: i did it in root but the error above was occured...

Comment: Please read this guideline about how to answer correctly a question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer